# How to show MvxDialogFragment using ShowViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a MvxDialogFragment and I want to show that using ViewModel, similarly when a activity is showed from ViewModel using ShowViewModel. Is it possible? How can I do that?

This is my scenario: I have a page that contains a MvxListView and, when the user click in a listview item, I want to show a MvxDialogFragment.

My ListView layout:

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
                    android:id="@+id/lstViewTasks"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:dividerHeight="1px"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Tasks; ItemClick ItemClickCommand"
                    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/projectmytasksitem" />
```

My ListView ViewModel:

```
public class ProjectMyTasksViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    #region [Atributos privados]

    private ProjectService _service;

    #endregion

    #region [Propriedades]

    private IList<Task> _tasks;
    public IList<Task> Tasks
    {
        get { return _tasks; }
        set { _tasks = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Tasks); }
    }

    private bool _isListaVazia;
    public bool IsListaVazia
    {
        get { return _isListaVazia; }
        set { _isListaVazia = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsListaVazia); }
    }

    private Task _selectedTask;
    public Task SelectedTask
    {
        get { return _selectedTask; }
        set { _selectedTask = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedTask); }
    }        

    private string _mensagemErro;
    public string MensagemErro
    {
        get { return _mensagemErro; }
        set { _mensagemErro = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => MensagemErro); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region [Commands]

    private IMvxCommand _itenClickCommand;
    public IMvxCommand ItemClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            this._itenClickCommand = this._itenClickCommand ?? new MvxCommand<Task>(this.ExecuteItemClickCommand);
            return _itenClickCommand;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region [Construtores]

    public ProjectMyTasksViewModel()
    {
        _service = new ProjectService();
        this.CriaListaTeste();
        IsListaVazia = (Tasks.Count > 0) ? true : false;
    }

    #endregion

    #region [Execuções dos Comandos]

    private void ExecuteItemClickCommand(Task task)
    {
        Dictionary<string, Task> parametros = new Dictionary<string, Task>()
        {
            {"Task", task }
        };

        this.ShowViewModel<TaskViewModel>(parametros);
    }

    #endregion

    #region [Métodos]

    public void CriaListaTeste()
    {
        Tasks = new List<Task>();

        for (int indiceProjeto = 1; indiceProjeto <= 10; indiceProjeto++)
        {
            Tasks.Add(new Task { Name = $"Tarefa {indiceProjeto}", StartDate = DateTime.Now, FinishDate = DateTime.Now, IsCompleted = false });
        }
    }

    #endregion        
}
```

My Listview Activity:

```
[Activity(Label = "My Task",
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation,
    ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class ProjectMyTasksView : MvxActivity
{
    public new ProjectMyTasksViewModel viewModel
    {
        get { return (ProjectMyTasksViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
        set { base.ViewModel = value; }
    }        

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ProjectMyTasksView);
    }
}
```

My Dialog Fragment:

```
public class ProjectMyTaskDialog : MvxDialogFragment<TaskViewModel>
{
    public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedState)
    {
        base.EnsureBindingContextSet(savedState);

        this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.ProjectMyTasksDialog, null);

        return base.OnCreateDialog(savedState);
    }
}
```

My Dialog Fragment ViewModel:

```
public class TaskViewModel : BaseViewModel<TaskService, Task>
{
    #region [Atributos Privados]

    private readonly IMvxPictureChooserTask _pictureChooserTask;

    #endregion

    #region [Commands]

    private MvxCommand _chooseImageCommand;
    public MvxCommand ChooseImageCommand
    {
        get
        {
            _chooseImageCommand = _chooseImageCommand ?? new MvxCommand(ExecuteChooseImageCommand);
            return _chooseImageCommand;
        }
    }

    private MvxCommand _takePictureCommand;
    public MvxCommand TakePictureCommand
    {
        get
        {
            _takePictureCommand = _takePictureCommand ?? new MvxCommand(ExecuteTakePictureCommand);
            return _takePictureCommand;
        }
    }

    private MvxCommand _completeTaskCommand;
    public MvxCommand CompleteTaskCommand
    {
        get
        {
            _completeTaskCommand = _completeTaskCommand ?? new MvxCommand(ExecuteCompleteTaskCommand);
            return _completeTaskCommand;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region [Construtores]

    public TaskViewModel(IMvxPictureChooserTask pictureChooserTask)
    {
        _pictureChooserTask = pictureChooserTask;
    }

    #endregion

    #region [Execuções dos Comandos]

    private void ExecuteChooseImageCommand()
    {
        _pictureChooserTask.ChoosePictureFromLibrary(400, 95, OnImage, () => { });
    }

    private void ExecuteTakePictureCommand()
    {
        _pictureChooserTask.TakePicture(400, 95, OnImage, () => { });
    }

    public void ExecuteCompleteTaskCommand()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion

    #region [Métodos]

    public void Init(Dictionary<string, Task> parametros)
    {
        Objeto = parametros["Task"];
    }

    private void OnImage(Stream imageStream)
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        imageStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

        Objeto.Image = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
    #endregion

    public class Parametros
    {
        public string TaskJson { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to modifiy the ViewPresenter. Here is a great article on navigating to fragments: http://gregshackles.com/presenters-in-mvvmcross-navigating-android-with-fragments/

Comment: But Greg is a contributer and I know, there have been a lot changes around fragments. So if you are lucky, it is already in the core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no presenter for DialogFragments.

Instead you could have instantiate the Command from the Activity or have a callback into the Activity which determines what to do when the command is called, i.e. displaying the Dialog.

So for a simple example:

```
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public Action ShowTaskCommandAction {get;set;}

    private MvxCommand _showTaskCommand;
    public ICommand ShowTaskCommand =>
        _showTaskCommand = _showTaskCommand ?? (_showTaskCommand = new MvxCommand(DoShowTaskCommand));

    private void DoShowTaskCommand()
    {
        CommandAction?.Invoke();
        // do other stuff here...
    }
}
```

Then in your Activity or Fragment:

```
public class MyActivity : MvxActivity<MyViewModel>
{
    public void OnCreate(Bundle _)
    {
        base.OnCreate(_);
        ViewModel.ShowTaskCommandAction = () => {
            var dialogFragment = new ProjectMyTaskDialog() {
                DataContext = task
            });
            dialogFragment.Show(FragmentManager);
        };

        // whatever else code
    }
}
```

Comment: How do we add parameters in the Show ?

Comment: @Magnas Not sure you can here. The new presenter on Android coming soon in MvvmCross, will support dialog fragments out of the box. Where it will be possible to just navigate to it using the navigation service. Hence, adding whatever parameters you want.

Comment: Okay thanks, so using a newInstance(...) pattern method to pass parameters is still a good idea if we need to bind some data to the Dialog ?

Comment: For now, I'd say yes.